# What happens when you try to hibernate but there is not enough swap available?

Tags: linux, memory, hibernate, swap

I have a Linux box with a swap partition of size RAM + *x*. Suppose more than *x* of the swap is already in use. Now I try to hibernate. Will the kernel

- randomly kill sleeping and/or not sleeping processes until there is enough swap free to hold the RAM
- not hibernate and warn/ask to proceed?

Or will this situation never happen because the kernel always reserves enough swap to safely hibernate?

Can I configure the behavior?

Edit: If this makes a difference, I'm currently using Ubuntu 12.04 with Linux 3.2.0-39-generic and hibernate with `pm-hibernate`.

Comment: Don't really know how linux filesystems work, or if this is relevant, but I tried running a Wordpress install on a server with 128MB of RAM and it didn't handle traffic well - the server would literally freeze to where I couldn't even input commands to stop Wordpress / reset - had to actually press the button.. My guess would be that it wouldn't kill any processes, but that's just a guess.

Comment: from my experience it will freeze your computer. At least it did that for me on arch linux..

Answer (score 2):

on later versions of linux kernels you are required to have a swap to hibernate. But there are work arounds. you can setup a swap file anywhere without partitioning.

Read about it here.
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/power/swsusp-and-swap-files.txt

a quick solution (credit to Robert Munteanu)

```
Create the swap file : dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024 count=8388608 ( 8GB )
Setup the swap file: mkswap /swapfile
Only when you need to set suspend you can activate it: swapon /swapfile
When you resume you can deactivate it: swapoff /swapfile
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to trigger swapoff /swapfile automatically after resuming?

Comment: I will ask a friend. I am sure its possible. Ill let you know asap